# CSSTransition duration doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, css, css-transitions, css-animations, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to implement slide down animation by using [CSSTransition](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition/), but it seems like `duration` of `transition` doesn't work.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZoVmE?editors=1111)

**component.jsx**

```
let { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } = ReactTransitionGroup

class Example extends React.Component {

    state = {
    show: false,
  };

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({
          show: true })}>Show</button>
          {this.state.show && (
            <CSSTransition in={this.state.show} timeout={2000} classNames="birthday-input" appear>
              <div className="form-group birthday-input">
                <h1>HEADER</h1>
              </div>
            </CSSTransition> 
          )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**component.scss**

```
.birthday-input-enter {
  max-height: 0;
}
.birthday-input-enter-active {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
.birthday-input-exit {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
.birthday-input-exit-active {
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the library documentation:
When the `in` prop is toggled to true the Component will get the `example-enter` CSS class and the `example-enter-active` CSS class added in the next tick. This is a convention based on the `classNames` prop.

First, in your case `in` never evaluates to true because `showBirthInput` is `undefined`.

Second, it has to do something with the JS evaluation because if I take out JS evaluation and instead ask `CSSTransition` to render on `show` it works perfectly.

Here's the working example based on your code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pshw1h?file=index.js

Comment: I edited my question. If you open codepen, there is no `showBirthInput `. Maybe it is because I was missing `unmountOnExit`. Thanks.